# XPath for text based on content in preceding element?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

```
<div class="profile-row">

        <div class="profile-cell">

            <h4 class="">Telephone</h4>

        </div>

        <div class="profile-cell">

            <p class="">0207 289 2981</p>

        </div>

    </div>
```

I am trying to grab the phone number: `0207 289 2981`

Using variations of:

```
//h4[starts-with(., 'Telephone')]/following-sibling::div[@class='profile-cell']
```

and:

```
//h4[starts-with(., 'Telephone')]/following-sibling::div/p
```

Can't seem to grab this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siblings have a common parent; `h4` and `p` do not.

Use `following::` instead.

This XPath,

```
//h4[.='Telephone']/following::p[1]/text()
```

will select the text of the immediately following `p` from your targeted `h4`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the xpath.

```
(//div[@class='profile-cell']//p)[last()]
```

The problem in your xpath is there is no sibling div to the h4. so you have to access the parent div and then select the sibling div as shown below.

```
//h4[starts-with(., 'Telephone')]/parent::div/following-sibling::div[@class='profile-cell']/p
```

Answer (score 0):

This selects the actual number:

```
//p[@class='']/text()
```